# Windows 10 on my Dell 7410 keeps locking itself when im idle for a few minutes

Tags: windows-10, laptop, dell-latitude, lock-screen

After about a minute, the screen dims, and another minute later the screen locks itself. This happens even while i am in a meeting or watching a video when im not moving my mouse. All while the laptop is charging and not in battery mode.

What ive tried:

- Disabling all power saving options
- Adding the registry key / grppolicy as described [here](https://windowsloop.com/disable-lock-screen-windows-10/)
- Checking that dynamic lock is disabled - here windows tells me that some options are managed by my company

How can i make absolutely sure that windows will never, ever, lock itself on its own without me manually telling it to?